# adding to a favorites page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, favorites

As a Flutter beginner, I'm currently working on a project where I have a list of hadiths, and each hadith has a 'Favorites' button. I want to implement a functionality where clicking the 'Favorites' button adds the respective hadith to a 'Favorites' page. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this in Flutter? I already have the list of hadiths and the button, but I'm not sure how to handle the logic for adding a hadith to the 'Favorites' page upon button press.

this is the list:

```
List<Hadith> hadithList = [
Hadith(
hadithNumber: 1,
hadith:
>           'hadith 1',
translation: 'Translation of Hadith 1'
> )
```

this is the code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'hadith_data.dart';
import 'settings_page.dart';
import 'index_page.dart';


class HadithPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const HadithPage({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HadithPageState createState() => _HadithPageState();
}

class _HadithPageState extends State<HadithPage> {

  bool isFavorite = false; // Track favorite status


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isEndOfList = widget.index >= hadithList.length - 1;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF5E6CA),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hadith ${widget.index + 1}'),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF8B5C3E),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      hadithList[widget.index].hadith,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text(
                      hadithList[widget.index].translation,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                        color: isFavorite ? Colors.red : null,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isFavorite = !isFavorite;
                          if (isFavorite) {
                            // Add to favorites list
                            // FavoriteHadith().addFavorite(hadithList[widget.index]);
                          } else {
                            // Remove from favorites list
                            // FavoriteHadith().removeFavorite(hadithList[widget.index]);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              if (widget.index > 0)
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => HadithPage(index: widget.index - 1),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: isEndOfList
                    ? null  // Null onPressed disables the button
                    : () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HadithPage(index: widget.index + 1),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),

        bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          canvasColor: const Color(0xFF8B5C3E),
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              label: 'Favorites',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
              label: 'Index',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Settings',
            ),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {

              if (index == 1) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IndexPage()), // Navigate to the FavoritesPage
                );
              } else if (index == 2) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IndexPage()), // Navigate to the IndexPage
                );
              } else if (index == 3) {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsPage()), // Navigate to the SettingsPage
                );
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried creating a function

```
 // Method to add a hadith to favorites
  void addFavorite(Hadith hadith) {
    if (!favoriteHadithList.contains(hadith)) {
      favoriteHadithList.add(hadith);
    }
  }

  // Method to remove a hadith from favorites
  void removeFavorite(Hadith hadith) {
    favoriteHadithList.remove(hadith);
  }
}
```

but can't see the changes

Comment: If you call `FavoriteHadith().addFavorite(...)`, that's basically creating a new instance of `FavoriteHadith` in place and adding the favorite hadith to that newly created instance.

Comment: The Flutter docs has an example of adding shopping items to a cart screen, which is very similar to the behavior you're trying to get: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code it might help you.
generate list of Boolean and manage accordingly.

```
    var favList = [];
  var favBool = <bool>[];
  List<Hadith> hadithList = [
    Hadith(
      hadithNumber: 1,
      hadith: 'hadith 1',
      translation: 'Translation of Hadith 1',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    favBool = List.generate(hadithList.length, (index) => false);
    super.initState();
  }
```

and handle like below,

```
Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: hadithList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                hadithList[index].hadith,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(
                hadithList[index].translation,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  favBool[index] ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: favBool[index] ? Colors.red : null,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (hadithList.contains(hadith)) {
                      favBool[index] = false;
                      favList.remove(hadithList[index]); 
                    } else {
                      favBool[index] = true;
                      favList.add(hadithList[index]);
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

and use favList in your favourite page.